# issue when downloading pdf in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, download

I'm downloading a PDF using the following code in asp.net

```
 try
            {
                string strURL = Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("PDFs/PrintPDF")).SingleOrDefault();

                WebClient req = new WebClient();
                HttpResponse response = HttpContext.Current.Response;
                response.Clear();
                response.ClearContent();
                response.ClearHeaders();
                response.Buffer = true;
                response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=\"" + strURL + "\"");
                byte[] data = req.DownloadData(strURL);
                response.BinaryWrite(data);
                response.End();//At this line I am getting the error

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
            }
```

The above code is working. But going to Catch Block and displaying error :

```
"[System.Threading.ThreadAbortException] = {Unable to evaluate expression because the code is optimized or a native frame is on top of the call stack.}"
```

I've replaced the response.End();line with this Line

```
HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
```

The pdf is getting downloaded but unable to open the PDF. While opening the PDF iam getting the error:

```
"there was an error opening this document. the file is damaged and could not be repaired"
```

I also tried using `response.Flush();` with no help:

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure of the intent of the error message but I got around the error by testing to see if the message contains the "Thread is being aborted" message.  Here's an example:

```
        if (ex.Message.StartsWith("Thread") == false)
        {
            Response.Redirect("~/Error.aspx?ErrorMsg = " + ex.Message);
        }
```

Also,

Please check this link reason and solution of the error: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/312629/EN-US/

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this can help you, to open PDF file from stream I use the following code that works fine for me and does not fire any exceptions. I get my pdf from a db, and for pdf file I don't use the addHeader. I hope it can help you.

```
Response.ClearContent();
Response.ClearHeaders();
Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
var abyt = (Byte[]) ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["blob"];
Response.BinaryWrite(abyt);
Response.Flush();
Response.Close();
```